# How to control font appearance in Manipulator input field?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Apologies for making something that is probably trivial my first question here but I just realized I do not know how to style the font within the input field in a Manipulator control. None of the options for this function are for styling within the input field (AFAIK). I wondered whether an input field option would work:

```
Style[Manipulator[0.5, Appearance -> {"Open", Tiny}], 
 DefaultOptions -> {InputField -> {BaseStyle -> Directive[Red, 16]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

but it didn't. I'm assuming this is trivial but it has me stumped.

**Edit**

I have tried using a local Manipulator style

```
Cell[StyleData["Manipulator"],
 ShowStringCharacters->False,
 NumberMarks->False,
 FontFamily:>CurrentValue["PanelFontFamily"],
 FontSize->24,
 FontColor->RGBColor[1,0,0],
 FontWeight->"Bold"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is changing the font colour and weight (I do not want these changed in my application, just testing what works and what doesn't) but still not changing the font size. If this stylesheet solution worked I guess it would suffice for now but ultimately I would like to have a tiny manipulator in a Manipulate:

```
{{x, 40, "Hello World"}, 20, 100, 5, Appearance -> "Open", 
AppearanceElements -> {"InputField", "StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton",    
                        "HideControlsButton"}, ImageSize -> Tiny}
```

but with a non-tiny font in the input field, and achieve this by direct coding.

Comment: Using the `Style` options `PaneBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Directive[...]}` or `DynamicBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Directive[...]}` will both change the font colour - but not the font size.

Comment: Using Style seems to override the LabelStyle of the Manipulate ... (the actual implementation which is within a Manipulate).

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch, we made it to the [commitment phase](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica). Thanks for your help. We could still use some more help, though, and if you could, would you commit to the next phase?

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know to change the size of the text in the field is to hit the entire thing with `Magnification`.  Using Simon's guidance above to do this with `Style`:

```
Style[
  Manipulator[0.5, Appearance -> {"Open", Tiny}], 
  DynamicBoxOptions -> {BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 2}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As above, when the Manipulator is the control element in a Manipulate these sort of Style settings mess other things up. I'm really looking for something local to the manipulator input field. BTW for the above I prefer a syntax that doesn't reference the underlying box names e.g. `Style[Manipulator[0.5, Appearance -> {"Open", Tiny}], 
 DefaultOptions -> {Dynamic -> {BaseStyle -> Magnification -> 3}}]`.